# Parsing JSON response in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json

I am working on an iOS json client for a php webservice and for some reason I'm having problems parsing a fairly simple json response from the server. What do I need to do?

**Edit**
The problem isn't the parsing so it must be the jsonString I'm sending the webservice.

Basically I need to send this

POST values
app = mark
data = { "01,E1,AT333AT333,9053839719,2012-08-28 14:35:58,2012-08-28 14:35:58,43.154650,-79.3877390,1000,YS3DD55H812035739,1000000,3434" }

The current code is printing null for both strings.

Here's my method that handles the call to the webservice.

```
- (IBAction)submitMessage
{
    NSString* apps =@"mark";
    NSString* data = @"01,E1,AT333AT333,9053839719,2012-08-28 14:35:58,2012-08-28 14:35:58,43.154650,-79.3877390,1000,YS3DD55H812035739,1000000,3434";
    NSDictionary* jsonDictionary=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: data forKey:@"data"];
    NSString* jsonString = [jsonDictionary JSONRepresentation];
    self.outPut.text=jsonString;
    NSLog(@"Made it");
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://secure.g4apps.com/g4webservices.php"];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient=[[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
    NSDictionary *params =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           apps,@"app",
                           jsonString,@"smpdata",nil];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"g4webservices.php" parameters:params];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
            NSLog(@"Response: %@ %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"Status"], [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"Data"]);
            self.outPut2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"response: %@ %@",[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"Status"], [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"Data"]];    }
                        failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error,id JSON){
                                         NSLog(@"[Error]: %@", error);
    }
];

    [operation start];


}
```

Here's a sample json response.

```
{

"Status":"11",
"Data":["AT333AT333,43.1547986,-79.3884892",
"BT343BT343,43.1547986,-79.3884892"]

}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I'm getting a null response for both strings.

Comment: Have you tried `NSLog(@"%@", JSON);` in your success block to see what's coming back?

Comment: No, I didn't know how to do that. The JSON value is appearly null so I don't know what I done wrong because I pretty sure the server should never return null.

Comment: This is weird if I purposely create an error, it returns and parses the error message fine from the server. It must have something to do with the json string I'm sending and not the parsing.

Comment: This is definitely a wierd issue. It not the string I'm sending as the Web Service is entering those properly into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the JSON string I was sending. The service was not using key value pairs for the json string it was receiving and I was unable to figure out how to reproduce that in Objective-C.

Post Variable where as follows
app="app_name"
data={ "Some csv data" }

What I was able to get Objective C to produce was
app="app_name"
data={ "Data":{"Some csv data"} }

So I modified the server to handle what iOS produced and now everythings working. Figure out how to handle the response when the Data array has more than one value.

Answer (score 2):

iOS 5+ now has built in APIs for parsing JSON.

See [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5) tutorial for more information.

Also, you can read the [NSJSONSerialization docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I will okay look at that. I will also need POST data to the server to get a response and the example doesn't cover that so I will need to do some searching.